# C# .Net CKEditor issue v4.4.6 in IE 11 'SCAYT is undefined'

Tags: ckeditor, runtime-error, internet-explorer-11, scayt

I have a C# .Net web app.  We have been using v3.6.2 for several years.  With IE 11 being released, CKEditor needs to be upgraded in our app since 3.6.2 does not support IE 11.  I have followed the instructions on the CKEditor site for download and install.  We use the SCAYT plugin. However, I am experiencing an error: 'SCAYT is undefined'.  I have been Googling but with not luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: IE11 is already a bit old at this point.. do you mean ie12? The SCAYT and WSC plugins I think need to be separately downloaded if I recall correctly. Can you try to get them separately? http://ckeditor.com/addon/scayt I won't add this as an answer yet because I'm not at all sure that this is the case, it's just IIRC

Comment: @Nenotlep...no, I meant IE 11.  I'll take a look at the downloads and post another comment.

Comment: @Nenotlep...I downloaded the scayt plugin but I'm still getting the error.  I opened a ticket on the CKEditor website in case you're interested.  Thx for the feedback. https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12849

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: @Reinmar...yes I cleared cache

Comment: Good idea to open a ticket. This sounds very strange indeed. Do you see the browser downloading the scayt plugin.js? That should at least give some info if it's missing. If you use the combined minified source it might be a good idea to debug with the "raw" sources.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upgrade my WebSpellChecker (which is a server app) to the newest version 4.4.6.  We were previously using WebSpellChecker 3.6.2.  Problem solved.